# ModelViewSet does not provide `create` url in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I have a viewset as below:

```py
class EntryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Entry.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EntrySerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsOwnerStaffOrReadOnly]
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, CustomOrderingFilter]
    filterset_class = EntryFilterSet
    ordering_fields = ["created_at", "last_update"]
    ordering = "created_at"

    @method_decorator(cache_page(60 * 5, key_prefix="entry"))
    def list(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().list(*args, **kwargs)

    @method_decorator(cache_page(60 * 60, key_prefix="entry"))
    def retrieve(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().retrieve(*args, **kwargs)
```

...which is added to `urls.py` of the related app using `DefaultRouter` as:

```py
_router.register("entries", EntryViewSet, basename="entry")
```

However, doing `reverse("api:entry-create")` fails to find `create` on my test. I also quickly check the URLs with Django Extensions subcommand `show_urls` but it does not print `api:entry-create`, which means it is not registered. What I do:

```sh
python manage.py show_urls | grep "api:entry"
```

The result is:

```
/api/entries/   api.viewsets.entry.EntryViewSet api:entry-list
/api/entries/<pk>/      api.viewsets.entry.EntryViewSet api:entry-detail
/api/entries/<pk>\.<format>/    api.viewsets.entry.EntryViewSet api:entry-detail
/api/entries\.<format>/ api.viewsets.entry.EntryViewSet api:entry-list
```

...which shows only `entry-detail` and `entry-list` are registered *while my model clearly is not `ReadOnlyModelViewSet`*.

Why do I not have `api:entry-create` url?

---

## Environment

- django ^2.2
- djangorestframework ^3.12.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `detail` views when you want to do something with a particular resource using its `pk` (`/resource/<pk>`), `list` when you don't have / don't want to use a `pk`. So `list` can be used to GET `/resource`, but also POST `/resource` to create a new one. Of course, POST `/resource` is mapped to the `create` method.

Comment: Actually, that makes sense, yet it is still still counter-intuitive to not have `create` URL as an alias to `list` in this case. Whatever, though, I think imma stick with it.